# Selenium checking checkbox

Tags: java, selenium

How can I select the following check-box, if I only have these attributes?

```
<input style="font-size: 30%" onclick="remove_descriptions( this );" onchange="remove_descriptions( this );" type="checkbox">
```

I have tried several ways using xPath but I have had no luck.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
```

**UPDATE**

I cannot edit the HTML or CSS files.

Comment: are there other checkboxes at page?

Comment: Yes there is a couple.

Comment: add extra class to your checkbox and `findElement(By.className("myCheckbox"))`

Comment: I would but I do not have access.

Comment: Analize other elements on page and figure out what difference between target checkbox and others.

Comment: Can you try temporarily putting a WebDriverWait (or even a `Thread.sleep(5000)`) before your findElement() call? If that doesn't work, can you post the console output?

Comment: add some more of the surrounding html, from there it will be a lot easier to help you out by providing a working xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want keep using XPath to select it, a good idea is find a tag with an ID that your checkbox are inside and start the selector using this reference. An example:

```
<div id="my-id">
   <input type="checkbox" class="my-class">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="my-class">
</div>
```

The selector to find the 3rd element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@id='my-id']/input)[3]"));
```

The selector to find the 2nd element with class "my-class":

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@id='my-id']/input[@class='my-class'])[2]"));
```

If necessary, you can try find it by label and select ancestors tags with xpath parent. After, you easily can navigate children tags by xpath